# Converting boundary points from a .kml using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, kml

I have this boundary that I received from a kml, I was able to dig down the xml and grab just the boundary points. I need to convert the points from this :

-92.25968002689014,30.7180061776264,0 -92.25976564548085,30.71751889774971,0 -92.25992462712097,30.71670626485147,0 -92.26006418327708,30.71604891951008,0 -92.26018466460856,30.71558863525373,0 -92.26037301574165,30.71498469610939,0 -92.26054805030229,30.71444051930294,0 -92.26065861561004,30.71411636559884,0

To This:

POLYGON((-92.25968002689014 30.7180061776264, -92.25976564548085,30.71751889774971, -92.25992462712097 30.71670626485147, -92.26006418327708,30.71604891951008, -92.26018466460856 30.71558863525373, -92.26037301574165,30.71498469610939, -92.26054805030229 30.71444051930294, -92.26065861561004,30.71411636559884))

The regex pattern I am using is : **",[0-9.-]* *"** 
My plan was to use a regex replace to replace any commas followed by any number of digits, periods, or minus signs followed by one or more spaces with some character like a colon. Then replace all commas with spaces and then replae all colons with commas. But for some reason I can't get it to work. Any Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't really even need regex. Trim the last number, join as a string and append/prepend the needed part.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
([-\d.]+),([-\d.]+),([-\d.]+)\s+([-\d.]+),([-\d.]+),([-\d.]+)\s*;
```

**Sample c# code:**

```
String polygon(String input)
{
    string pattern = @"([-\d.]+),([-\d.]+),([-\d.]+)\s+([-\d.]+),([-\d.]+),([-\d.]+)\s*";
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline;
    String finalString = "POLYGON((";

    int count = 0;
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
    {
        if (count > 0)
            finalString += ",";
        finalString += m.Groups[1] + " " + m.Groups[2] + ", " + m.Groups[4] + "," + m.Groups[5];
        count = 1;
    }
    finalString += "))";
    return finalString;    
}
```

**output:**

```
POLYGON((-92.25968002689014 30.7180061776264, -92.25976564548085,30.71751889774971,-92.25992462712097 30.71670626485147,
 -92.26006418327708,30.71604891951008,-92.26018466460856 30.71558863525373, -92.26037301574165,30.71498469610939,-92.260
54805030229 30.71444051930294, -92.26065861561004,30.71411636559884))
```